# fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Github error: failed to push some refs to

Tags: git, github, git-bash

Trying to add a csv file which is big using Git bash. I have cloned the repository where it exists in my git bash too and it exists by name `origin`. However I am unable to push csv file into origin.

Code to push Filename.csv into my github. The below code works fine.

```
$ git push origin master
$ cd path_of_directory
$ git lfs install
$ git lfs track "*.csv"
$ git add Filename.csv
$ git commit -m "Filename.csv"
$git remote add origin 'https://github.com/Shailaja-Gupta/Marketing-and-Sales-Machine-Learning.git'
$git remote
origin
```

Code with a problem

```
$ git push origin master
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Replacing origin with the https link gives below error:

```
$ git push 'https://github.com/Shailaja-Gupta/Marketing-and-Sales-Machine-Learning.git' master
--->ref master:: Error in git rev-list --stdin --objects --not --remotes=https://github.com/Shailaja-Gupta/Marketing-and-Sales-Machine-Learning.git --: exit status 128 fatal: bad object 3cc9272e299e6c7a9cbfe02b36060691f7f86b17

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Shailaja-Gupta/Marketing-and-Sales-Machine-Learning.git'
```

Comment: have you access to this repositor?

Comment: yeah. Its my repository only

Comment: hm > I see. You are from windows?

Comment: I checked this repository. It's exist

Comment: yes................

Comment: first delete github credentials token from windows. 
for doing go to this photo and follow. 
https://prnt.sc/rtf4j5

Comment: It looks like you are trying to login with incorrect credentials. Either doing what @ArifulIslam should help. Or, preferably, you can setup ssh key (you can generate one using git gui) and setting copying it to your Github profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following steps worked for me:

```
$git init
$git add .
$git commit -m 'message'
$git remote add origin 'https://github.com/Shailaja-Gupta/Marketing-and-Sales-Machine-Learning.git'
$ git pull --rebase origin master
$ git push origin master
```

This worked for me